# How can I use ANORM in play console?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, anorm

I'd like to use ANORM to connect to db in play console, just simply test some stuff. But there's some errors when I create a DataSource

```
val ds=DB.getDataSource()
java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start an application from within the play console:

```
[My application] $ console
scala> import play.core.StaticApplication
import play.core.StaticApplication

scala> new StaticApplication(new java.io.File("."))
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
res0: play.core.StaticApplication = play.core.StaticApplication@...
```